# Are there caveats not having a permanent address?

Tags: usa, legal

I'm in California today and my apartment lease expires in two months.

I'd like to tour the country for a bit - move all my stuff into storage, go on a plane and live in hotels or air bnbs for a bit.

Are there any downsides I should be aware of with not having a permanent address (incl. Utilities) for a bit? I'd get a PO Box so I can still get mail, but I don't want to pay for an apartment if I'm not there.

(no parents or other family in the country whose address I could use)

Comment: I think I read about this virtual mailing address, they receive your mail and scan it and email it to you.. or something like that... maybe that will work for you.

Comment: First thing I could think of: check if your bank / credit cards are fine with that? Could you have correspondence addressed to you c/o your parents or a friend for all instances when asked for an address in forms?

Comment: I've been a wanderer for two years.  My mail goes to my parents, but when asked my address, I almost always say that I don't have one.

Answer (score 5):

One example: if someone tries to sue you, and you have no permanent mailing address to receive the court papers (and hard to locate), the court might permit to notify you through other means - such as using your old last known mailing address, or through a declaration in a newspaper popular in that area. Then the court would consider you being served, and will rule without your appearance - and in almost every case you're better be there.

Another issue could be automatic traffic tickets (toll, some parking, red light cameras) - they are sent by mail to your car register address. Failure to address them promptly might lead to penalties, registration issues and even possibly arrest warrants.

Comment: There are also income tax implications, which would be better covered at the Expatriates site, and which can be very complex.